Correcting data using model residuals
I am trying to follow a method from a paper to correct my data for technical effects. The method suggests to take the central portion of my data to guard against outliers (which I can do), fit a generalised additive model to that data (which I can do), and then apply that model to the full dataset (which I can do).  The method then states:
"After fitting the regression model, compute model residuals for the full dataset and use these residuals to compute index values adjusted for technical effects"
How do I use residuals from the full dataset to adjust my index values (the original data points)?

What are these "technical effects"?  How could any model correct for them? The residuals from a model are supposed to be noise.   Do you have a missing variable in your model?

Is this time series? Are you trying to add some AR/MA terms to the residuals which your model did not capture?
